# How to edit e-mail settings for project issue content type

Tags: 7

I am using the [project](https://www.drupal.org/project/project) and the [project issue](https://www.drupal.org/project/project_issue) module on a Drupal 7 instance and ran into some trouble with the notification settings.

Apparently, the `poject issue` module saves for every content type a variable which contains information which e-mail sender address should be used for e-mail notifications on new issues etc.
The variable is named `project_issue_reply_to_NAME_OF_CONTENT_TYPE`. 
**How can I change this value for an existing content type?**

As the variable is of type `blob` I can't change the value easily in the database.

Answer (score 1):

suggestion 1 :

drush vset project_issue_reply_to_NAME_OF_CONTENT_TYPE test@example.com

suggestion 2 :

in a custom hook_update_N() :
variable_set('project_issue_reply_to_NAME_OF_CONTENT_TYPE', 'test@example.com');